# SQL Server Calculated Field - Data from a parent record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, calculated-field

I'm trying to see if I could obtain a value from a parent relationship within the same table.

In the example below, `Parent_ID` is a relationship to a parent.
`RouteName` should ideally be a calculated field that selects the direct parent's routename (or name if null).

This way, I could create a complete route by only selecting the direct parent and would save iterating or CTE'ing across all records.
Is that possible?

```
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| ID | Name             | RouteName                           | Parent_ID |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| 1  | Parent           | NULL                                |           |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| 2  | Child 1          | Parent - Child 1                    | 1         |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| 3  | Child of Child 1 | Parent - Child 1 - Child of Child 1 | 2         |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: How many levels of _parenthood_ are you expecting? If not pre-defined, recursion would be the only reasonable solution.

Comment: I've got a limit of three - pretty much exactly as above.

Comment: If I could obtain the direct parent's name in a calculated field, where I could concatenate the present name into, then my problem would be solved.
Pseudo: If Parent_ID Is not null then Select Parent.Name + ' | ' + this.name

Comment: IF you expect no more than three levels, you can either create a hierarchical query or its equivalent join. I personally prefer the first.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you'd do that in a calcualted field? The end goal is to be able to select the records, whereby the RouteName contains the concatenated name.

Comment: Just to clarify: For my queries etc I use a CTE hierarchical query. What I'd like to achieve here is to be able to query Child of Child 1 (ID3) and see the complete route to it.

Comment: I see... say, provide two IDs and, if there is a parental path between them, display it (or update the field of one of them in the table). Did I get you right?

Comment: Let's say you insert ID 4, Name "Child 2 of Child 1", Parent_ID 2. Then the (persisted) autocompute-column would look up the RouteName of ID2, and concatenate ID 4's name to that.
The result would be Parent - Child 1 - Child 2 of Child 1.
The same process would have happened when ID 2 Child 1 was inserted - it looked up its own parent's name and created its RouteName  with the same process.
I simply don't know if I'll be able to get this into a computed column.

Comment: I see... I change my suggestion. I would simply create a trigger ON INSERT and deploy the correct value along with the new (provided) values.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a trigger, but I suppose there might not be another option. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, there are other options, but this is the simplest. By the way, if my comments helped you, you may consider up-voting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function for the computed column

```
drop table MyTable
drop function dbo.fn_CalculateRouteName

create table MyTable
(
    ID int,
    Name varchar(100),  
    Parent_ID int
)
go

create function dbo.fn_CalculateRouteName(@ID int)
returns varchar(max)
begin
declare @rtn varchar(max);

with cte (ID, Name) as (
    select Parent_ID, convert(varchar(max), Name) From MyTable where ID = @ID
    union all
    select MyTable.Parent_ID, convert(varchar(max), MyTable.Name + ' - ' + cte.Name )
    from cte
    inner join MyTable on cte.Id = MyTable.ID 
)
select @rtn = max(Name)
from cte

return @rtn
end
go

alter table MyTable add RouteName AS dbo.fn_CalculateRouteName(ID);

insert into MyTable(ID, Name, Parent_ID) values(1, 'Parent', null);
insert into MyTable(ID, Name, Parent_ID) values(2, 'Child 1', 1);
insert into MyTable(ID, Name, Parent_ID) values(3, 'Child of Child 1', 2);

select * from MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you James, I'll try this. If I persist that column the performance overhead might not be too significant I reckon? I'm still pondering the trigger solution FDavidov suggested but will try and report back. I'll accept the answer after testing if that's allright.